# C++ Class Variables: Initialization vs. Assignment and Initialization of vectors

Tags: c++, class, initialization

I am working on a C++ program that has a series of class variables that contain vectors on some or all of the member variables.  My question is three-fold:

1. Is it straight-forward to use constructors to initialize vector variables that are part of a class (see sample class definition below)?  Could someone post an example constructor for the class below (or for at least the single and two-dimension vector variables)?
2. Is there a problem with simply initializing the variables myself in my code (i.e., iterating through each element of the vectors using loops to assign an initial value)?
3. Along the same lines, if the variables need to be initialized to different values in different contexts (e.g., zero in one instance, some number in another instance), is there a way to handle that through constructors?

Sample class definition:

```
class CreditBasedPoolLevel {
public:
    int NumofLoans; 
    int NumofPaths; 
    int NumofPeriods; 
    double TotalPoolBal;

    vector<int> NumofModeled;
    vector<double> ForbearanceAmt;
    vector<double> TotalAmtModeled;

    vector<vector<int>> DefCountPoolVector;
    vector<vector<double>> TermDefBalPoolVector;
    vector<vector<double>> BalloonDefBalPoolVector;
    vector<vector<double>> TermDefBalPoolVectorCum; 
    vector<vector<double>> TermSeverityAmt;
    vector<vector<double>> TermELAmtPoolVector;
    vector<vector<double>> BalloonELAmtPoolVector;
    vector<vector<double>> TermELAmtPoolVectorCum;

};
```

Comment: Are you asking for "how to fill the vectors with some useful content in the constructor"?

Comment: Just resize, assign and push back what you need in the constructor.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yes...

Comment: Your title asks about the difference between initialization and assignment, but then you use *initialize* throughout the question when you mean *assign*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In C++, initializing a variable calls its constructor.  In a vector's case, this means it creates an instance of a vector with whatever the initial capacity is (10 I believe), with no values.  At this point, you need to use push_back in order to fill the vector - even though it has a capacity, it will cause undefined behavior if you try to access unfilled areas directly (such as with NumofModeled[0]).  You can also initialize it with some amount of space by using vector NumofModeled(x) (x being the number of spaces), but generally because vectors have dynamic size, it's easier to use push_back unless there is some reason you need to enter your data out of order.
2. Relates to the capacity part of one, if you try to access unfilled space in a vector you will get undefined behavior.  It's pretty standard practice to fill a vector with a loop though, such as:

   ```
   vector<int> v;
   int in = 0;
   while (cin)
   {
      cin >> in;
      v.push_back(in);
   }
   ```
3. Yes, but remember that like functions, constructors only differentiate by the type of input parameters.  So, for example, you could have `CreditBasedPoolLevel(int level)` and `CreditBasedPoolLevel(vector<int> levels)`, but not another with the definition `CreditBasedPoolLevel(int otherint)`, because it would conflict with the first.  If you want to be able to take different contextual input of the same type, you can use another variable to define the constructor type, such as `CreditBasedPoolLevel(int input, string type)` and use a switch block to define the initialization logic based on the type.

Comment: `at()` will throw an exception, `operator[]` will just cause undefined behavior.

Comment: (I fixed your code block -- code blocks inside numbered and bulleted lists need even more indentation, just keep hitting space in front until the preview changes to a code block)

Comment: Ahh, it looks like Ben is right about undefined behavior.  If one were to use `operator[]` to fill the vector, would size update?

Comment: It's undefined behavior to use `operator[]` with an invalid index, so no one can say for certain that the size won't change... but I've never met an implementation where it would.  `operator[]` is supposed to be very lightweight and efficient, and bounds checking and resizing would violate that goal.  As you said, changing the size and then using `operator[]` to assign all the elements is viable if a bit clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

As for question number three, simply add a constructor with an argument that is the value you want to initialize the vectors with.

And if you just want the vectors to be default constructed, then there's nothing that needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor may look something like this:

```
CreditBasedPoolLevel::CreditBasedPoolLevel()
{
   const int numDefCountPools = 13;
   const int numDefCountPoolEntries = 25;

   for(int i = 0; i < numDefCountPools; i++)
   {
      vector<int> v;
      for(int j = 0; j < numDefCountPoolEntries; j++)
      {
          v.push_back(j + i * 5);  // Don't know what value you ACTUALLY want to fill here
      }
      DefCountPoolVector.push_back(v);
   }
}
```

Note that this is ONE solution, it really depends on what values you want, how you went them organized, etc, what is the "right" solution for your case.